# How to calculate standard error when using command nlcom by hand?

Tags: standard-error

I used Stata to run the regression as follows:

$y = b_{0} + b_{1}x + b_{2}x^2 + e$

and code:

`regress y x c.x#c.x`.

Then I want to calculate the marginal effect of x with respect to y at mean:

$dy/dx = b_1 + 2.b_2.mean(x)$

I use nlcom command to calculate this effect:

```
sum x
scalar meanx = r(mean)
nlcom _b[x] + 2*_b[c.x#c.x]*mean
```

Then it gives me the marginal impact of x on y and also the standard error of that estimation (standard error of
 {$b_1 + 2b_2*mean(x)$})
 How do you calculate this by hand?

Comment: Why are you not using `lincom`, since it's linear? I believe nlcom is equivalent to lincom in this case, and standard error is calculated by the square root of the variance, where $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+2Cov(X,Y)+Var(Y)$.

Comment: I think that in my case it should be: var(aX +bY), where a = 1 and b = 2*mean(x)